# Angular 6 + Bootstrap 4 Making ngFor divs hidden

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have an array of items, of which I want to only display 3 at a time. To do so, I wanted to do the following:

```js
displayItems(input: number){
    return (Math.floor(input / 3) + 1 == this.page)
  };
```

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <div *ngFor="let sItem of qls.itemArray; let i = index">
      <div *ngIf="qls.displayItems(i)" class="card">
        Test
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I know this doesn't run, I'm new to stack overflow still so I apologize, but it's the code I have. Essentially, it'll only display 3 items based on the page. The issue is, the ngFor loop will generate a div for every object in the array, which itself has display:block attached to it. Because of this, it will mess with flex, and instead of showing three items at a time neatly, it'll make space for all twelve but only display 3 at a time.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to make the generated ngFor divs hidden? Maybe some sort of applying a class to its parent and applying display:hidden, or something. I'm also open to alternative solutions that aren't flex-box based.

Thanks in advance, please let me know if additional clarity is needed.

Comment: use <ng-container> instead of div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let sItem of qls.itemArray; let i = index">
    <ng-container *ngIf="qls.displayItems(i)" class="card">
      Test
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi!  why is better to use ng-container? i always use div.
something related to css? or native controllers?

Comment: `ng-container` is a pseudoelement, where `div` is a real one.It won't affect depth in your CSS classes

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the div tag in the ngfor loop use ng-container tag

Comment: can you tell me why, please ?

Comment: Because op said they didn't want to render the div associated with the ngfor loop

Answer (score 0):

Why not create an array of groups to display and loop that. It'll make it simpler to manipulate it if you have other needs. Something like:

```
 items: Item[];
displayItems: <Item[]>[];

constructor(
    private _service : YourService
)
{
    this._service
    .getItems
    .subscribe(items =>
       {
           this.items = items;
           this.displayItems = this.groupItems<Item>(items);
       }
    );
}

groupItems<T>(items: T[], groupSize: number)
{
    var groups = <T[]>[]; 
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i += groupSize) 
    { 
        groups.push(items.slice(i, i + groupSize)); 

    } 

    return groups;
}
```